# How to call a function and pass some arguments with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get multiprocessing working with some CPU bound tasks. However, I cannot figure out how to call a function in the child process and potentially pass in some argument to perform out-of-band tasks. any help is appreciated.

child.py

```
import multiprocessing
def Performer( multiprocessing.Process ):

    def __init__( self, taks_queue ):
        super().__init__()
        self.taks_queue = taks_queue
        self.term_str = "done"

    def set_term_str( self, term_str ):
        self.term_str = term_str

    def run( self ):
        while True:
            task = taks_queue.get()
            if task == self.term_str:
                while taks_queue.qsize() > 0:
                    taks_queue.get()
            else:        
                handle_task(task)
```

parent.py

```
import multiprocessing
def Generator( multiprocessing.Process ):

    def run( self ):
        taks_queues = [multiprocessing.Queue( -1 ) for i in range(5)]
        for i in range(5):
            perfs.append(Performer( taks_queue = taks_queue[i] ))
            perfs[i].start()

        while True:
            message = get_message()
            mod = check_message(message)
            if mod != 0:
                term_str = get_term_str(mod,message)
                perfs[mod].set_term_str(term_str)

            handle_task(task)

if __name__=="__main__":
    gen = Generator()
    gen.start()
    gen.join()
```

generator communicates with outside world and needs to change term string when needed. how would I be able to call functions of another multiprocessing.Process and pass some arguments to alter execution behavior of the multiprocessing.Process?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 main options:

1. use Value() to declare share memory, that is available to both parent and child. You can use ints or strings as shared values. see http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects
2. Put the term_string into the child's task queue. when the child pops from the queue, it needs to check the value.

BTW for what you want, python already provides the great mechanism of a subprocess worker pool, see http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

Comment: thanks for trying, but I will be passing several pickable object as parameter, so shared memory doesn't help. pool is not suitable because I would need to change term_str base on message and it's expected that the Performers will have different term_str after first few messages.

Comment: then you must push the term_str via the queues. you can't do what you tried to do in your code.